# Why are Stripes appearing on my Textures in D3D11 when I Enable NVidia Optimus

Tags: c++, windows, nvidia, directx-11

**Background**: I've been using the integrated GPU for shader debugging, but I think it might've hit it's limit which prompt me to use dedicated graphics.

The only problem is, when I add NvOptimusEnablement to my code, stripes started showing on my textures; What's interesting is that the stripes doesn't show up in Visual Studio's Graphics Analyzer.

In Windows: [image: From Windows]

In Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer: [image: From Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer]

I Wouldn't have mind it if the artifacting is only present for debug builds, but the executables also displays these striped textures.

**Things of note:**

it seems that adding the line:

```
extern "C" 
{
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = SomeValue;
}
```

Will result in D3D11 using dedicated graphics regardless the value of 'SomeValue', even if SomeValue is 0; I have to remove this block of code to use integrated graphics.

--

I noticed that enabling Optimus uses quite a bit more memory (61.4MB vs 37.4MB using integrated graphics, according to Visual Studio's Process Memory) I don't have any experience with this kind of programming so I don't really know if this is normal, but I thought I might as well write down my observations.

**Edit:**

My code currently has quite some abstraction, but the things I write here should be the same exact order.

{Begin Call}

Compile shaders ..

Setting up sampler

```
ID3D11SamplerState * pSampler = nullptr;
..
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC default_sampler = {};
default_sampler.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
default_sampler.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
default_sampler.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
default_sampler.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
default_sampler.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
default_sampler.MinLOD = 0;
default_sampler.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
m_d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&default_sampler, &pSampler);
m_ImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &pSampler);
```

Loading the texture

```
//Loading Image from file
ID3D11ShaderResourceView * pTextureRV = nullptr;
..
auto ext = std::filesystem::path(filename).extension();
if (ext == ".dds")
{
    DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile(m_d3dDevice, filename.c_str(), nullptr, &pTextureRV);
}
```

Setting up Vertices ..

{Draw Call}

Setting the Texture to PSShaderResource for the square pattern

```
m_ImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, &pTextureRV);
```

Setting up Shaders

```
m_ImmediateContext->VSSetShader(VShader, nullptr, 0);
m_ImmediateContext->PSSetShader(PShader, nullptr, 0);
```

Setting up Constant Buffers ..

Drawing the Triangle

```
m_ImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(index_count, 0, 0);
```

{Shader}

Main Shader:

```
cbuffer CBResize : register(b0)
{
    matrix Projection;
    float2 Screen;
};

cbuffer CBFrame : register(b1)
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
};

struct Vin
{
    float3 Pos : POSITION;
    float4 Col : COLOR;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct Pin
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Col : COLOR0;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

Pin VS(Vin input)
{
    Pin output;
    output.Pos = float4(input.Pos, 1);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);
    output.Col = input.Col;
    output.Tex = input.Tex;
    return output;
}

//t2 contains square pattern
Texture2D txFrame : register( t2 );
SamplerState samLinear : register( s0 );

float4 PS(Pin input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return txFrame.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);
}
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, your video card driver only looks for the presence of the symbol, it does not care about the value. The stripes are possibly a) something wrong in your code (so please show it) or b) a driver bug.

Comment: My code is getting quite big now, so I don't think it's right to copy-paste everything, but I've edited my post to include the codes I use to load the texture, sampler, and the shader itself. I'm also currently debugging the frame using Visual Studio's Graphics Analyzer to check the context's state and values, Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: After searching for D3D11 samples and enabling Optimus, I think it's safe to conclude that the stripes came from an error in my code, I don't know what it is yet, but I'll keep looking

Comment: I've made another discovery, for some reason the problem fixes itself if I use slot 0 for the texture, but any other slot, it gives me the striped texture

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure what happened, but after updating Windows 10, and reinstalling Visual Studio and NVidia's drivers (clean install), it looks like the problem's fixed now? Thank you for the assistance!

leaving a note here just in case:

Processor: i7 6700HQ

GPU: GTX 960M

Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041.329

NVidia Driver Version: 451.48

Visual Studio Version: 15.9.24